# How can i list every container that has been stopped on my html page

Tags: python, docker

I wrote this code so i can remove all my stopped docker containers.
Now i want to display all stopped containers on my web page so i can get an overview of the stopped containers. The code now only outputs the last removed container on de web page

```
   import docker
   client=docker.from_env()
#-------------------------
   stopped_containers = client.containers.list(filters={'status': 'exited'})

   for container in stopped_containers:
       container.remove(force=True)
       message = (f"Removed containers {container.name}.")
       print(message)

   return message
```

This is the output of the print(message)

```
Removed containers ubu05888.
Removed containers ubu09215.
Removed containers ubu08385.
Removed containers ubu02408.
Removed containers ubu06971.
```

i change the code a couple of times and messed with the return statement but cant seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding `message` in each iteration. Just add to it instead:

```
...
message = "Removed containers:"
for container in stopped_containers:
    container.remove(force=True)
    message += f" container.name"
return message
```

or better simply build the `message` string:

```
...
message = "Removed containers: " + ", ".join(c.name for c in stopped_containers)
return message
```